# .Net Core Radio Button always returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am sending a List to the view.
Trying to submit each item in the list through a form.

**Model:**

```
 public partial class Model
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UId { get; set; }
        public int WId { get; set; }
        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

        public virtual AspNetUsers User { get; set; }
        public virtual WModel W { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult UWC()
{
    List<Model> uW = db.UW.Include(x => x.U).Include(x=>x.W).ToList();
    return View(uW);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UWC(Model uW)
{
    var s = ModelState.ErrorCount;
    return RedirectToAction("UWC");
}
```

**View**

```
@model List<Model>
            <table  class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].W.Name)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].W.Type)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].W.Description)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].W.IsActive)
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @for (var item = 0; item < Model.Count(); item++)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[item].W.Name)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[item].W.Type)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[item].W.Description)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <form asp-action="UserWidgetConfiguration" asp-controller="UserManagement" method="post">
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model[item].IsEnabled, true, new { @Name = "IsEnabled",, id = "enabled_" + item } })<label>True</label>
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model[item].IsEnabled, false, new { @Name = "IsEnabled" ,, id = "disabled_" + item }})<label>False</label>
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[item].Id" value="@Model[item].Id" name="Id" />
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[item].WidgetId" value="@Model[item].WidgetId" name="WidgetId" />
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[item].UserId" value="@Model[item].UserId" name="UserId" />
                            </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('input[type=radio]').change(function () {
                $(this).closest('form').submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

The above is the complete code.

The radio button is always binding to false.

**However,
I am using a script to submit the form onchange of radio button value:**

```
  <script>
        $(function () {
            $('input[type=radio]').change(function () {
                var data = JSON.stringify($(this).closest('form').serializeArray());
                console.log(data);
                $(this).closest('form').submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**The console gives the proper value for the radio button.**

```
[{"name":"[0].IsEnabled","value":"True"},{"name":"Id","value":"1"},{"name":"WId","value":"1"},{"name":"UId","value":"a"},{"name":"__RequestVerificationToken","value":"CfDJ8FLfqW1-k2hNlQsGtRBQVqOKRWmlkQYWTMrEQNcJHWGd7_LPvHfjw3V5gxYAnLjwz7HvjExZDXgmbSMQ1DnEONg7EJfu5OqYm7xntqXIe4IMkD1HD4SHRtihdyzDXHrKu7jNXUwuN1B6H-565O0J0oZsGVCopZqy180oPco29vqyvpcZkZnWEOmVQX6_V3T6AQ"}]
```

When I am expecting a true value for IsEnabled in the controller I am getting a false value.

But the value is true as expected when the form is serialized and displayed in the console.

Is this because of the event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array prefix in the name of the radio inputs (`[0].IsEnabled`) causes the inputs not to be mapped in the model, as the name is expected to be `IsEnabled`.
As simple workaround you could just create the inputs manually without the HTML Helpers, e.g.:

```
<input type="radio" name="IsEnabled" value="True"/> <label>True</label>
<input type="radio" name="IsEnabled" value="False"/> <label>False</label>
```

See the [source](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/NameAndIdProvider.cs,6c254ac4cb0d90b5,references) of the helper for additional details.